# GET image/gif com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

**Tentei isto porém o utilitário para Developers do Google Chrome reconhece dataType como** *xhr*

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/img/img.gif",
            dataType: "image/gif",
            cache: true
        });
});
```

Comment: Podes explicar como vais utilizar essa imagem? queres mostrar na página ou enviar o conteudo da imagem algures?

Comment: quero que a imagem carregue quando a página carregar, nao vou usa la no html.

Comment: Porque não pões a imagem no HTML com `display: none;` e depois mostras a imagem quando a página tiver carregado? Esse AJAX vai buscar o url da imagem?

Comment: só quero coloca-la em cache automaticamente

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kevin, 
Boa noite.

Na realidade quando você faz uma requisição ajax, através de um $.ajax, $.post, $.get, as requisições sempre vão ser um XHR, mas o conteúdo da resposta pode ser um datatype: jpeg, gif, png, text/html, etc.

O Developer Tools, mostra o tipo de requisição que ele está fazendo quando disparado através do src de um `Image`, ele entende que você tá carregando uma imagem.

Quando você faz a requisição através de um objeto `XHR` (`XMLHttpRequest`), ele entende que é um `AJAX`, portanto aparece na aba XHR.

Na prática:

```js
//Vai em network -> Images
var img = new Image();
img.src = "http://images.forbes.com/media/lists/companies/google_416x416.jpg";


//Vai aparecer em network -> XHR
$.ajax({
 type: "GET",
 url: "http://images.forbes.com/media/lists/companies/google_416x416.jpg",
 dataType: "image/jpg",
 cache: true
});
```

Resposta 2:

Para colocar uma imagem no cache, a melhor alternativa é usar o `Expires Header`, caso você esteja utilizando o Apache, você pode procurar nesse link:

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_expires.html

Comment: Vc basicamente fez oq eu fiz... O conteúdo nao é codificado em gif..

Comment: Sim, a ideia era ilustrar a onde cada requisição aparecia na aba Network do Google Developer Tools. Mas agora entendi que o que você quer, é adicionar uma configuração de cache para sua imagem, logo adicionei uma segunda resposta.

Comment: quero que quem nao ou sim tenha a imagem em cache, obtenha assim que entrar no site, com expires header tb é possivel?

Comment: Sim, utilizando o mod expires do apache vc consegue definir um período de cache para cada tipo de arquivo. Assim, quem n tem o arquivo no cache vai passar a ter..